# Pouring bottles into buckets but not too much: how to configure Maximum Flow with Lower Bounds to solve this assignment problem?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, upper-lower-bounds, discrete-optimization, network-flow

### Problem

- $n$ jars of water with different volumes $v_i$ have to be assigned to $m$ empty buckets with different volumes $V_j$
- $n \ge m$.
- A jar can only be poured into 1 bucket.
- Multiple jars can be poured into the same bucket.
- All jars have to be completely empty at the end.
- No bucket can be left completely empty.
- We want to find the assignment that minimizes the sum of the volume left empty across buckets (deficit), and the total amount of water that overflowed (excess).

### What I tried

So I tried to map this problem to the [Maximum Flow Algorithm with Lower bounds](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs498dl1/sp2015/notes/25-maxflowext.pdf): for an input bipartite graph $G$, a source $s$, a sink $t$, two function $l,u : E \rightarrow R^+$ we seek a flow $l(e) \leq f(e) \leq u(e)$ at every edge $e$

- arcs $(s,i)_{i\in[n]}$ have capacity $u(s,i) = l(s,i) = v_i$
- inner edges $(i,j){i\in[n],j\in[m]}$ have lower bound $l(i,j)=0$ and capacity $u(i,j)=v_i$
- arcs $(j,t)_{j\in[m]}$ have lower bound $l(j,t) = (1-\epsilon)V_j$ and upper bound  $u(j,t) = (1+\epsilon)V_j$.

That is, we are allowing for a fraction of the flow to go overload or underload. The attached paper explains how to modify the graph structure to find a feasible flow.

### Question

If this parametrization is correct (is it?), I don't know how to guarantee that the inner edges must have an integral value: I don't want the flow from one jars to be split across different buckets. I have read that the Ford–Fulkerson algorithm should proceed with integer values, but I am reaching the end of my knowledge here. Also sorry for butchering the formalism :'/

Comment: As stated, finding an optimal solution to this problem appears to have [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) as a special case.

Comment: thank you @MishaLavrov! You actually gave me a pointer to the class of problem I wanted! From link to link I ended up to the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) that is quite close from what I want :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether jar $i$ is poured into bucket $j$.  Let nonnegative decision variables $d_j$ and $e_j$ denote the amount of deficit or excess, respectively, for bucket $j$.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_j \left(d_j + e_j\right)$$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_i x_{ij} &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $j$} \tag2\label2 \\
\sum_i v_i x_{ij} + d_j - e_j &= V_j &&\text{for all $j$} \tag3\label3 \\
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns each jar to exactly one bucket.
Constraint \eqref{2} assigns at least one jar to each bucket.
Constraint \eqref{3} defines the deficit and excess for each bucket.

You cannot relax integrality of $x_{ij}$ and expect to get integer values.  The objective function would encourage splitting of $v_i$ to multiple buckets, yielding fractional values for $x_{ij}$.

Comment: wahoo this is so beautiful when the problem is described with the right formalism! I don't know anything about integer linear programming, but i guess it's time to learn :D thank you :3